# ComboBox Selected Value to be Blank

Tags: c#, winforms

Uses: VS 2012;

I've a combobox attached to a datasource in my form. And things work fine. When I run the form, again everything works fine; I can select an item in the dropdown list and it updates to the datasource as well. My problem comes when I need to deselect/revert what I have selected after I saved or Remove what I have select (basically should go as ***null*** for that field value).

Our legacy system was built in **Delphi 3 & 5**, and users got a feature of right-clicking on the dropdown list and get a small popup like button named

> Blank

which blanks what have been selected. I could not find anything that will do the same what ever user have selected in .NET's combo box.

Comment: normally, I'll just add one extra blank item at the bottom of the datasource.

Comment: Did you try setting the `SelectedIndex` to -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst thanking all of your Answers and suggestions, I used @V4Vendetta's idea and composed my solution.

Similarly to deleting a record in a datagridview where you click ***Delete*** key, I took the same concept and associated my solution with ***Delete*** Key.

What I did was created a handler for ComboBox's Keypress Event like:

```
private void comboBox_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
            (sender as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = -1;    
    }
}
```

And linked to every ComboBox's available

```
ComboBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(comboBox_KeyPress);
ComboBox2.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(comboBox_KeyPress);
```

Now when user clicks ***Delete*** key while the ComboBox selected/active, it gets blank.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new item in `dropdown` named `-Select-`( or something similar name) by using following code:

```
drp.DataSource = dataSet;
drp.DataBind();
// do it after binding
    drp.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-", "NA"));
```

If you are binding in xaml then on `page_load` event you can write only this line

```
 drp.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-", "NA"));
```

Now if user want to deselect choice, he/she will simply select `-Select-` item.